# Spring RestTemplate and HttpClient connection pooling limit

Tags: spring, connection, httpclient, resttemplate, pooling

I'm using RestTemplate on my jsf web server, and with these configuration I often reach limit of connection to routes so soon (exp:/ap-domain/get-all).

How can I release connection to avoid limit?

This is my config class:

```
@Configuration
public class RestTemplateConfig {

        @Bean
        public PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager poolingHttpClientConnectionManager() {
            PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager result = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
            result.setMaxTotal(100);
            result.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(20);
            return result;
        }



        @Bean
        public CloseableHttpClient httpClient() throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException {
            CloseableHttpClient result = HttpClientBuilder.create()
            .setConnectionManager(poolingHttpClientConnectionManager())
            .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig())
            .setSSLSocketFactory(csf)
            .build();

    return result;
        }

        @Bean
        public RestTemplate restTemplate() throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException {
            HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient());

            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);

            restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new RestResponseErrorHandler());

            List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptors = restTemplate.getInterceptors();
            if (interceptors.isEmpty()) {
                interceptors = new ArrayList<>();
            }
            interceptors.add(new RestTemplateHeaderInterceptor());
            restTemplate.setInterceptors(interceptors);

            return restTemplate;
        }
    }
```

My RestUtil to call api:

```
@Component
public class RestUtil {

    private static RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public RestUtil(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        RestUtil.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }

    public static <T> MessagesResponse<T> exchange(String url, HttpMethod method, Object requestObject, String token, ParameterizedTypeReference<MessagesResponse<T>> type) {

        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Is Autowired annotation supposed to be on the restTemplate field instead of the method in RestUtil class?

Comment: I think Constructor dependency injection is suit for this static factory class

Comment: Bit confused with your code..you are setting connection pooling details in poolingHttpClientManager but passing closeableHttpClient as parameter inside RestTemplate request factory..You may review it once..

Comment: I have add code implement detail in  httpClient() :D